# multiline import from X import Y as Z

Tags: python, import

Is there a way to use the `from X import Y as Z` idiom on a multiline import?

Specifically, I want to write something like `from some.very.long.package.name import LongName as OtherLongName`. The whole thing does not fit in one line.

So I tried to write it using parentheses to cross lines, but I found some strange behavior with the `as` keyword. Specifically:

```
#this is just fine
from os import (
  path)

#this is a syntax error
from os import (
  path) as os_path
```

The only way I have figured out to do what I want is therefore:

```
from some.very.long.package.name import (
  LongName)
OtherLongName = LongName
```

Is there any way to do it in one statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a slash where you want to stop:

```
from some.very.long.package.name import \
                 LongName as OtherLongName
```

Without it Python will think the line is over and throw `SyntaxError`.

You can also use [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) if you find operations on strings more convenient:

```
from importlib import import_module
OtherLongName = import_module('some.very.long.package.name.LongName')
```

Comment: This is a readability problem also because the import statement is embedded in a function. Using the slash forces the next line to not use any indentation, which makes the result hard to read.

Comment: @aestrivex you can also use [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) to operate with strings.

Comment: importlib is a great suggestion. I dislike the slash operator aesthetically and think the importlib solution is a lot cleaner. thanks!

Comment: @aestrivex whoopsie, I confused you. `importlib` module exists in STL from Python 2.7. Full featured `importlib` module was introduced in Python 3.1. Sorry :(